# Typearea Problem using twocolomn Layout in scrartcl document

Tags: koma-script, two-column, typearea

Running this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titlehead{Titlehead}
\title{Title}
\subject{Manuskript}
\author{It's me}
\date{28. Februar 2018}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\tableofcontents

\section{Einleitung}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Fazit}

\end{document}
```

results in this warning:

```
Package typearea Warning: Maybe no optimal type area settings!
(typearea)                The maximum limit of line width is about 29%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically detected line width.
(typearea)                You may e.g. increase DIV, decrease fontsize
(typearea)                or change the papersize.
```

This confuses me, since I would expect KOMA-Script to find a optimal solution with `DIV=calc` even for a twocolumn layout. The paper format is also nothing uncommon.

The font size needs to be reduced to 9pt in order for the errror to disappear which is too small to read imho.

Any idea what causes this warning and how I can fix it?

Comment: Warning, not error.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right. nevertheless i'm still looking for a solution

Comment: Add `\recalctypearea` after loading another font and settings (lmodern and setspace).

Comment: @TeXnician using `\recalctypearea` slightly changes the width of the type area. While clears some of the `underfull vbox` warnings, the typarea warning still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *similar* warning and the problems of typearea are known to the KOMA developer Markus Kohm. He describes in [this external thread](https://komascript.de/node/1793) (in German) the following:

> typearea versucht bei zweispaltigen Dokumenten jede Spalte optimal
>   groß zu machen. [...] Dann werden natürlich die
>   Spalten natürlich noch kleiner, obwohl sie schon jetzt nicht die
>   maximale Größe für die angegebene Schriftgröße erreichen.
>
> typearea kann keine Wunder. Es kann auch nicht hellsehen. Es hat daher
>   Grenzen.
>
> Es gibt übrigens noch eine Möglichkeit, das Optimum bezüglich des
>   Satzspiegels heraus zu holen: fontsize=8pt. Allerdings möchte das dann
>   niemand mehr lesen …
>
> Von dieser letzten, spaßigen Bemerkung abgeleitet, der ernsthafte
>   Hinweis Mit fontsize=10pt und DIV=30 oder kleiner statt DIV=calc passt
>   die Fußzeile auf die Seite. Die Warnung, dass die maximale Zeilenlänge
>   (je Spalte) nicht erreicht wird, bleibt dabei natürlich.

which does roughly say:

- `typearea` tries really hard to optimize column width. But it cannot predict anything and has some limitations especially concerning head and foot.
- You can do some trickery to get the most out of the type area, but that would mostly result in a change of the font size.
- You could also manually try to find a good combination of font size and DIV, but warnings may still arise.

Comment: I've stumbled upon this as well. I thought it might be a different issue at the time.
so basically `typearea` is not capable of calculating a valid value for `DIV`, right?

Comment: @cles typearea tries to do the job of a good layouter, but cannot replace him, especially for twocolumn.